# Python defining range of input parameter for methode

Tags: python, parameters

Can I define a specific value range in a methode declaration? given a function like:

```py
def methode_range(value: int):
    print(str(int))
```

how can I specify a range in the methode parameter input field?

currently my code would be:

```py
def methode_range(value: int):
    if (value > 0) & (value < 5):
        print(str(int))
    else:
        raise Exception("Input value range")
```

but now I'm asking myself: is there a better way? Like the same way you can define the input type for the value, you can specify a range?

Comment: You could do `if 0 < value < 5:`, but what exactly is wrong with this? You could use assertions, e.g. `assert(0 < value < 5)`, but having an exception is the way to go.

Comment: Why are you printing `int` instead of `value`? Also, neither one needs to be cast to a `str` for printing.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy that is not my question, but yea it is not needed

Comment: It's IN your question, and it is wrong. It makes you seem very lost regarding what you are doing.

Comment: "the methode parameter input field" what *effect* do you expect that to have? You must understand, Python type hints are *hints*. They are not enforced at runtime (unless you are using some third-party library that implements that, or you implement it yourself). They way to do what you want is to do what you are doing, except you should really use the `and` operator instead of the bitwise `&`, and furthermore, in this case, you sould use `if 0 < value < 5`

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no. That said, you might want to use `typing.Annotated` to simulate this sort of [refinement type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_type).

```
from typing import Annotated, get_type_hints, get_args

def foo(x: Annotated[int, range(1, 6)]):
    x_hint = get_type_hints(foo, include_extras=True)['x']
    rng = get_args(x_hint)[1]
    if x not in rng:
        raise ValueError("x out of range")
    print(str(x))
```

`Annotated` itself has no built-in semantics, so the arguments can be used for whatever you like. Keep in mind, though, that while you can attach any number of annotations to a type, finding the annotation that *you* want from among various other annotations added for other tools might be challenging. For example, you might have something like `Annotated[x, foo, bar, baz]`. You might have to search through the list returned by `get_args` to find the particular expression needed for any particular use-case.